# iPhone custom font with text border/shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I'm using [Zynga's FontLabel](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) to use a custom font in my iPhone project. Is there a way to add a text border and shadow using this?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean around the entire label, this FontLabel class appears to just be a subclass of UILabel which has the following properties:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor        *shadowColor; 
@property(nonatomic)        CGSize          shadowOffset;
```

to control shadows.  Furthermore, UILabel is a subclass of UIView, each of which is backed by a CALayer, which has the following properties that allow you to apply a border to any CALayer:

```
@property CGFloat borderWidth;
@property CGColorRef borderColor;
```

You should be able to set these properties on the object returned by your UILabel's layer property.

If you were looking for "outlined text" you need to look for a font that encapsulates that behavior. I don't think the kit can just "figure that one out" for you.

HTH.